# Conditional Independent clarification

Tags: probability, independence

Let's say I have $3$ events with probabilities $P(A) = 0.5, P(B) = 0.5$ and $P(C)= 0.5,$ and I need to find if

$$P(A \cap B \mid C) = P(A \mid C)P(B \mid C)$$

I am tying to prove this by expanding the formula above to:

$$P(A \cap B \mid C) = \frac{P(A \cap C)}{P(C)}\frac{P(B \cap C)}{P(C)}$$

Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Your question is misstated: events are sets, not numbers. I assume you meant to write the respective probabilities of $A,B,C$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Your expansion of $P(A\cap B\mid C)=P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C)$ is correct, but is there some additional information about the events? Knowing only that $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=0.5$, you can find sets $A$, $B$, $C$ that satisfy the condition $P(A\cap B\mid C)=P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C)$, and other sets that don't.

Comment: @grand_chat `your expansion of... is correct, but...` I disagree.  there is no reason to believe $Pr(A\cap B|C)=Pr(A|C)Pr(B|C)$.  The expansion going from $Pr(A|C)Pr(B|C)=\frac{Pr(A\cap C)}{Pr(C)}\cdot \frac{Pr(B\cap c)}{Pr(C)}$ is, but your comment might be interpreted that the statement wishing to be proven is true.

Comment: @JMoravitz This was exactly grand_chat's point, wasn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation as stated without additional assumptions on the independence of $A$ and $B$ is false.  Consider the following counterexample.

Consider the experiment where we flip two fair coins in sequence.  We have the equiprobable sample space $\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$

Let $A$ be the event that the first coin is a head.  $Pr(A)=0.5$

Let $B$ be the event that the first coin is a tail.  $Pr(B)=0.5$

Let $C$ be the event that both coins show the same result.  $Pr(C)=0.5$

$A\cap B$ is then the event that the first coin is simultaneously a head and a tail.  This is clearly an impossible scenario regardless of what it is conditioned on.

$A\cap C$ is the event that both coins are heads.  $Pr(A\cap C)=0.25$

$B\cap C$ is the event that both coins are tails.  $Pr(B\cap C)=0.25$

$$L.H.S.=Pr(A\cap B|C) = \frac{Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}{Pr(C)} = \frac{0}{0.5}=0$$

$$R.H.S.=Pr(A|C)\cdot Pr(B|C)=\frac{Pr(A\cap C)}{Pr(C)}\cdot \frac{Pr(B\cap C)}{Pr(C)} = \frac{0.25}{0.5}\cdot\frac{0.25}{0.5}=0.25$$

These are unequal.

---

Even if $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ are independent events, we would have:

$$Pr(A\cap B|C) = \frac{Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}{Pr(C)}=\frac{Pr((A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C)}{Pr(C)} \\
= \frac{Pr(A\cap C)}{Pr(C)} \cdot Pr(B\cap C) = Pr(A|C)\cdot Pr(B\cap C)=Pr(A|C)\cdot Pr(B\cap C)\cdot \frac{Pr(C)}{Pr(C)} \\
=Pr(A|C)\cdot Pr(B|C)\cdot Pr(C) \neq Pr(A|C)\cdot Pr(B|C)$$